# how to read sonar data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sonarqube

I need to read sonar datatype file in python. Sonar data contains the ocean details, It used to measure the depth of the sea. The file contains binary data and extension as .s7k format.

Comment: If you Google "xtf python", the very first hit is a GitHub project for reading xtf files.  I'm thinking you didn't look very hard before coming here.

Comment: Tim Roberts searched google to read  .s7k format but not able to found any solution. Then only posted here.

Comment: Then you may need to convert it by hand to something you CAN read.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/CCOMJHC/common_data_readers/blob/master/python/reson/s7k/reader.py)?

Comment: There is another example [here](https://github.com/hydroffice/hyo2_openbst/blob/bd16667ecfaafc2514e7016ff2adf5d4467c3a09/hyo2/openbst/notebooks/openbst.Getting_started.ipynb) which may be useful. Try searching github instead of google, with terms like s7k py reson sonar etc

Comment: @Mercury Getting error ERROR : Cannot install hyo2-qc==3.5.12 and hyo2-qc==3.5.4 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded a sample s7k file to test whether I could read it---and I could. (The sample file I used to test can be downloaded [here](https://bitbucket.org/hydroffice/hyo_openbst/downloads/20190730_144835.s7k).)

1. First, in a new project folder, download this [dg_formats.py](https://github.com/CCOMJHC/common_data_readers/blob/master/python/reson/s7k/dg_formats.py) file, which contains a list of reson datagram codes and helpers.
2. Next, download this [reader.py](https://github.com/CCOMJHC/common_data_readers/blob/master/python/reson/s7k/reader.py) file to the same folder.
3. **Line #9** of reader.py is the following:

   ```
   from hyo2.openbst.lib.raw.parsers.reson.dg_formats import parse, ResonDatagrams, reson_datagram_code
   ```

   Change this to:

   ```
   from dg_formats import parse, ResonDatagrams, reson_datagram_code
   ```

   Basically we skip installing the hyo2-qc library, we just take the parsing and reader code.

Afterwards, I can simply do:

```
from pathlib import Path
from reader import Reson
from dg_formats import parse, ResonDatagrams, reson_datagram_code

input_path = Path("20190730_144835.s7k") # the sample I downloaded

sonar_file = Reson(input_path)
sonar_file.is_mapped()
```

We can check the attributes with the class dict:

```
>>> sonar_file.__dict__
{'_valid': True,
 'data': None,
 'map': {7200: [[64, 1564498115590.0002, 334, 386]],
  7022: [[466, 1564495196916.9998, 32, 0]],
  7001: [[566, 1564495197011.0015, 7699, 0]],
  7021: [[8333, 1564498114898.9983, 20116, 0],
   [2340566, 1564498116758.9988, 20116, 0],
   [5031198, 1564498118618.9995, 20116, 0],
...
 '_reson_sync_patt': 65535,
 'format_type': 's7k',
 'file_length': 88684918,
 'file_location': 88684918,
 'file_end': True}
```

We can also see a list of map keys like this:

```
>>> print(sorted(sonar_file.map.keys()))
[1003, 1012, 1013, 7000, 7001, 7002, 7004, 7007, 7010, 7021, 7022, 7027, 7028, 7058, 7200, 7300, 7503, 7504, 7610]
```

This is basically what information is inside. From `dg_formats.py`, we can match the code and see what's what. For example, `1003` is position, so:

```
>>> position_data = sonar_file.get_datagram(ResonDatagrams.POSITION)
>>> print(position_data)

[<dg_formats.Data1003 at 0x7f4946c1c5e0>,
 <dg_formats.Data1003 at 0x7f4946c1c130>,
...
...
 <dg_formats.Data1003 at 0x7f493e28d880>]

# let's get information of first position
>>> print(position_data[0].__dict__)

{'desc': 'Position', 'time': 1564498113624.0005, 'num_beams_max': 512, 'parse_check': True, 'header_fmt': '<If3d5B', 'header_size': 37, 'datum': 'WGS', 'latency': 0.0, 'latitude': 0.7517794800836651, 'longitude': -1.2341624217514013, 'datum_height': 1.32, 'position_flag': 0, 'qual_flag': 0, 'position_method': 0, 'num_of_satelites': 15}
```

There isn't helpers for all the codes (for example, nothing for 7200, 7300, 7503, 7504, 7610), but I hope it's a start to how to get info out of the file!

Comment: Mercury which tool you are using to access / open s7k file

Comment: I didn't use any tool. I just tried to see if I could get information from the s7k file with Python, like your question asked!

Comment: Thanks Mercury,  position_data = sonar_file.get_datagram(ResonDatagrams.POSITION)
NameError: name 'ResonDatagrams' is not defined

Comment: Add this line in your script: `from dg_formats import parse, ResonDatagrams, reson_datagram_code`